# Splitting Pipeline in sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, save, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with the following features:
visitor_id, feature_1, feature_2, ..., feature_100, truth_labels

I implemented the following model on sklearn:

**1st step**: scaling `df.drop(['visitor_id', 'truth_labels'], axis=1)` using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()`

**2nd step**: clustering `df.drop(['visitor_id', 'truth_labels'], axis=1)` using `sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans()` in **10 clusters**. Set `df['cluster']` to corresponding clusters.

**3rd step**: fit **10** `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()` on `df.drop(['visitor_id'], axis=1)`, one per cluster.

I have two questions:

1- Is it possible to build a `Pipeline` in order to aggregate these three steps? In particular, how can I specify that I want to train 10 distinct `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()` models on my data splitted by clusters?

2- Is it possible to save this full pipeline? How?

Comment: I think you'll need to create both a custom MiniBatchKMeans class including a `fit_transform` method and a custom Logistic Regression class to specify your desired training scheme. I don't think the objects will work in a pipeline OOTB. For example, all the n-1 objects in the pipeline simple call `fit_transform` and pass the result to the next object as input. Consider what `fit_transform` returns for `MiniBatchKMeans`: it's a distance matrix, which is not going to be useful when it gets passed to the LogisticRegression object. This is the reason I suggest making custom classes